# Rails where w/ associated habtm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I Have a rails setup like:

```
class Person
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sports
  ...
end

class Checkin
  belongs_to :person
  ...
end

class Sport
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :people
  ...
end
```

I want to get all checkins of People for a given day but only wheres where they have a HABTM record w/ the `name` of "Baseball". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work? (the attribute names may need to be changed)

```
Sport.where(:name => "Baseball").people.checkins
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having just the person_id in checkins table, you can have the sport_id as well. I think that's your requirement, right? A checkin is basically something a "Person" does for a "Sport".

Relationships could look like this:

```
class Person
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sports
  ...
end

class Checkin
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :sport
  ...
end

class Sport
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :people
  ...
end
```

Now, it'll be quite striaghtforward to get the checkin for a Sport. You can just do something like:

Checkin.where(sport_id: 1, person_id: 2)

In case you don't get the ids, you can do a join and get the results in 1 query.

Comment: A person is not tied to a single sport; They can have multiple sports which is the reason for the has_and_belongs_to_many on Person. The sport(s) is tied to the person themselves, not the checkin

Comment: Yup, my answer above does not tie a checkin to a sport. But a checkin can be tied to only one of them if im not wrong. Can a person checkin without a sport?